# Как склонять два существительных, идущих за одним числительным

Tags: склонение

Как правильно склонять два существительных, идущих за одним числительным: "в ящике было 21 яблоко и груша" и "в ящике было 22 яблока и груши"

Comment: Зависит от того, какую информацию пытаетесь донести. Ящик из арифметической задачки?

Comment: На мой взгляд, если продублировать числительное, то будет проще и понятнее.

Comment: Понимается очень просто: в ящике было 21 яблоко и (одна) груша" и "в ящике было 22 яблока и груши (пока в неопределенном количестве). Совокупность предметов соответствует форме ед. числа  ср.рода "было".

Comment: @athlonusm Так их всего 21/22. То есть сумма яблок и груш.

Comment: @oleedd Мне кажется, имеется в виду, как склонять два существительных, когда они относятся к одному числительному. Поэтому я предлагаю продублировать числительное: 21 яблоко и (21) груша, 22 яблока и (22) груши.

Comment: @athlonusm Думаю, тогда вопроса бы не было, потому что всё очевидно. Плюс в таких случаях нельзя пропускать второе число (маловероятно, что это).